# How to sort table rows and colums dynamically of mysql table in php

Tags: php, sorting

### How to sort table rows and colums dynamically of mysql table in php

```
+---+---+---+---+
| CR| C1| C2| C3|
+---+---+---+---+
| R1| 5 | 9 | 6 |
+---+---+---+---+
| R2| 1 | 7 | 2 |
+---+---+---+---+
| R3| 4 | 8 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

> How i can sort table in rows and cols wise.

```
+---+---+---+---+
| CR| C1| C2| C3|
+---+---+---+---+
| R1| 5 | 6 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+
| R2| 1 | 2 | 7 |
+---+---+---+---+
| R3| 3 | 4 | 8 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

> On clicking on the head of rows/cols, Data of that rows/cols have
>   sorting.

Comment: did you try to sort it from client side using jquery?

Comment: use [datatables](http://datatables.net/)

Comment: No,It this possible??

Comment: yes it is possible http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: But not using jQuery.Possible without JQuery??

Comment: php has sort() and ksort functions which sorts array by key and value, but as i know it sorts only one dimensional array. also you can write your own but if you use mysql why do you want to sort it from php just use order by clause.

Comment: I want sorting rows of table of html. Columns is sorting direct in sql query.. so plz help :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear.

If the output of a SQL query should be ordered, then use the "ORDER BY" clause in the SQL query.

The the output of a SQL query is being presented in a web page, and it is desired to have dynamically sortable output on the web page, then use `jQuery` and the `jQuery` `tablesort` module (see http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

See http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Getting-Started for details on how to prepare the HTML content to have dynamically sortable columns.

Comment: In tablesorter.com it just sort columns of table. I want sort rows data of html table....

Comment: Sorting rows is available as a `jQuery` module called `sortable`.  Just wrap each sortable row as specified in the `sortable` instructions.